# Mocking methods called within multiprocessing doesn't work on Mac

Tags: python, macos, mocking, pytest, python-multiprocessing

I encountered a very weird bug. In my project, I have unit tests where I mock some methods (download methods for instance) that are called within a multiprocessing operation.
Those unit tests work fine on my CI, but when I try to run them locally on Mac OSX, the mock isn't taken into account.

I implemented the following minimal reproducible example:

```py
# test_mock_multiprocessing.py
import multiprocessing
from typing import List
from unittest import mock

import pytest


def _f(x: float) -> float:
    return x**2


def f(x: float) -> float:
    return _f(x)


def map_f(xs: List[float]) -> List[float]:
    return list(map(f, xs))


def multimap_f(xs: List[float]) -> List[float]:
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        ys = list(pool.map(f, xs))
    return ys


@pytest.mark.parametrize("method", [map_f, multimap_f])
def test_original(method):
    xs = [-2, 3, 1]
    expected_ys = [4, 9, 1]
    ys = method(xs)
    assert ys == expected_ys


def mocked_f(x: float) -> float:
    return -x


@mock.patch("test_mock_multiprocessing._f", side_effect=mocked_f)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("method", [map_f, multimap_f])
def test_mocked(mocker, method):
    xs = [-2, 3, 1]
    expected_ys = [2, -3, -1]
    ys = method(xs)
    assert ys == expected_ys
```

That I launch with

```sh
pytest test_mock_multiprocessing.py
```

If I launch those tests within the Docker image python3.8-buster (with pytest installed), they are all successful.
But if I launch the same tests directly on my host machine (Mac OSX), within a virtualenv with only pytest installed, I have the following output:

```sh
$ pytest test_mock_multiprocessing.py
=========================================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: typeguard-2.13.0, cov-3.0.0
collected 4 items

test_mock_multiprocessing.py ...F                                                                                                                                                                    [100%]

================================================================================================= FAILURES =================================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________________ test_mocked[multimap_f] __________________________________________________________________________________________

mocker = <MagicMock name='_f' id='4377597216'>, method = <function multimap_f at 0x104e431f0>

    @mock.patch("test_mock_multiprocessing._f", side_effect=mocked_f)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("method", [map_f, multimap_f])
    def test_mocked(mocker, method):
        xs = [-2, 3, 1]
        expected_ys = [2, -3, -1]
        ys = method(xs)
>       assert ys == expected_ys
E       assert [4, 9, 1] == [2, -3, -1]
E         At index 0 diff: 4 != 2
E         Use -v to get the full diff

test_mock_multiprocessing.py:44: AssertionError
========================================================================================= short test summary info ==========================================================================================
FAILED test_mock_multiprocessing.py::test_mocked[multimap_f] - assert [4, 9, 1] == [2, -3, -1]
======================================================================================= 1 failed, 3 passed in 1.06s ========================================================================================
```

Comment: I fixed some naming issues in the code. I checked again and all the tests work when called within the python:3.8-buster docker image

Comment: I posted a possible answer - please check if this works for you (can't test it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the behavior under Linux and MacOs has probably to do  with the multiprocessing [start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method). On Linux, the default start method is `fork`, while on MacOS and Windows it is `spawn`.

If using `fork`, your processes are forked in the current state, including the mocking, while with using `spawn`, a new Python interpreter is launched, where the mock will not work. Under MacOs (but not under Windows) you can change the start method to `fork` in your test:

```py
@mock.patch("test_mock_multiprocessing._f", side_effect=mocked_f)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("method", [map_f, multimap_f])
def test_mocked(mocker, method):
    start_method = multiprocessing.get_start_method()
    try:
        multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork', force=True)
        ... do the test
    finally: 
        multiprocessing.set_start_method(start_method, force=True)
```

For convenience, you could also wrap that into a context manager:

```py
@contextmanager
def set_start_method(method):
    start_method = multiprocessing.get_start_method()
    try:
        multiprocessing.set_start_method(method, force=True)
        yield
    finally:
        multiprocessing.set_start_method(start_method, force=True)

...
def test_something():
    with set_start_method('fork'):
        ... do the test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's indeed working on Mac